# flush stdout inside numba jitted function

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, flush, numba

Apparently `numba` supports neither `sys.stdout.flush` nor `print("", flush=True)`.

What is a good way to flush "prints" inside a jitted function?

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3475

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`objmode()` context manager](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/withobjmode.html) to use code which is not supported in `numba`’s `nopython` JIT mode:

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def f(x):
    x *= 2
    with numba.objmode():
        print(x, flush=True)
    return x + 1

print(f'f(7) = {f(7)}')
# 14
# f(7) = 15
```

As noted in the documentation, this should only be used outside of performance-critical code sections due to the overhead involved.

Note: I don’t think this was available when the question was originally asked in 2017.